# counter_cpu_share_used com alerta vermelho - PowerPanel

Tags: powerpanel

```
Resource counter_cpu_share_used red alert on environment 170 dominio.com current value: 89 soft limit: 85 hard limit: 95
```

Por vezes no log de recursos da este aviso vermelho, o que me preocupa, a dúvida é.. Como posso debugar isso no PowerPanel? Tentei ver algo nos processos que estão sendo executado, mas não consigo entender como isso pode me ajudar.

Servidor é VPS.

Vou deixar printado o System Proccess, afim de facilitar o entendimento do meu cenário atual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa noite,

Não tenho experiência com power panel, mas tenho com outros softwares similares de gestão e no post tem poucas informações. Mas estudei um pouco materiais da net e vou tentar te ajudar.

Para começar, [aqui](http://download.parallels.com/doc/pva45/Parallels_Power_Panel_Users_Guide.pdf) há um PDF (em inglês), com informações de administração deste sistema.

Na página 62 (*Monitoring Operations and Viewing Logs*) fala um pouco sobre a exibição e configuração desses logs.

Isso está acontecendo porque o processamento atingiu um limite pré estabelecido no parâmetro `counter_cpu_share_used`. Para debugar, você tem que analisar a lista de processos em Container Services dashboard, indo no link *System Processes* e ver quais processos estão consumindo mais recursos, através da coluna TIME, você vê quais processos estão usando mais tempo da CPU. Daí precisa estudar se deverá mudar a aplicação/serviço ativo, restringindo o uso, caso possível, ou se deverá aumentar a CPU da sua VPS.

Pelo o que eu vi das imagens que postou, é um indicador quantitativo, ou seja, só conta o número de processos ativos. Isso só será um problema se a % da CPU estiver alta.

É comum o apache disponibilizar processos para cada conexão. [Aqui](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/httpservers/doc/v1319/9atperf.htm) há uma explicação detalhada disso e como limitar os processos (em inglês).

Segue um trecho:

> For example, Apache needs 1000 processes to handle 1000 concurrently connected clients, or connections.

tradução:

> Por exemplo, O Apache precisa de 1000 processos para lidar com 1000 clientes conectados simultaneamente, ou conexões.

Se o tempo da cpu (em %) não estiver auto, basta você ajustar o parâmetro `counter_cpu_share_used`, para um valor mais auto, caso contrário, você terá que estudar uma ação para esse serviço, seja melhorar processamento ou restringir usuários/conexões simultâneas.

Qualquer dúvida, estou à disposição.

Comment: Boa! Vou processar essas informações e volto após aqui para ver o que consegui entender, obrigado!

Comment: Printei ali(coloquei na postagem) a ultima parte dos processos na sessão System Proccess, o que me preocupa é o Command que parece repetido, com time alto(maior que os outros processos,.. Esse Command repete varias e varias vezes:  `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL`

Comment: Alterei a resposta com uma nova referência. Qual é a % do tempo da cpu? Se não estiver alta, você pode alterar o parâmetro, caso contrario, vai ter que analisar mais a fundo o que está gerando o consumo auto.

Comment: Não entendo quando diz: "Qual é a % do tempo da cpu",.. O que me estranha que a CPU usada diz 49%, quando o parametro `cpu_share_used` está quase estourando(perto dos 95 quando o limite é 95). Obrigado pela atenção, e pelo tempo tempo é claro.. valeu!

Comment: Disponha. Quanto à dúvida, porque o **_counter_cpu_share_used_** está contando o número de processos em uso enquanto os 49% do uso da CPU é o tempo que a CPU consome computando, em porcentagem. Isso significa que 51% do tempo ela está ociosa, por isso perguntei "Qual é a % do tempo da cpu". Acho que a solução seria somente mudar o parâmetro do log e colocar algo em torno de 130 processos como crítico, o que pelos dados que você me disse, representaria em media 70% do uso da CPU e não dária mais alertas desnecessários no log.

Comment: Eric, eu andei procurando como mudar o parâmetro `counter_cpu_share_used`, mas sem sucesso. Eu acredito que mudando esse parâmetro meu servidor vai deixar de cair(percebi que ele cai quando o valor corrente ultrapassa o limit(95)).  Como posso mudar esse valor? Mesmo assim se voltar a cair pelo menos deixaria de exibir estes alertas, o que já ajuda. Grato.

Comment: Alexandre, achei [aqui](http://kb.odin.com/en/117211) uma descrição detalhada do problema e como resolve-lo. (Em Inglês).

[Aqui](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204645150/troubleshooting-dv-memory-issues#2) também tem uma boa fonte de informação, para fazer um estudo nos processos e ver se é hack, defeito na aplicação ou se é normal.
Me parece que o buraco é mais embaixo do que estávamos pensando. Esse alerta, pelo o que diz nesse artigo, é realmente do uso da cpu e não um simples contador do número de processo. O que quer dizer que seu contêiner está realmente sobrecarregado.

Comment: Apenas para constar, eu resolvi mudar para um plano dedicado, e vou começar a trabalhar com memcached para deixar o servidor mais performático, thanks Eric, agradeço a persistência em meu caso, até mais.